# addGestureRecognizer to rightBarButtonItem with customView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

How I can add action to my `rightBarButtonItem` with `customView`?

Now I have code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configurePhotoProfile()
}

func configurePhotoProfile() {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let widthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
    let heightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true
    widthConstraint.isActive = true
    imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channel?.recipientUrlImage ?? ""))
    imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:))))
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.selectedSegmentedControl) == 0 {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

@objc func didTapImageButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("tap")
}
```

But if I tap on `barButtonItem` I can't see my `print("tap")` in console. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **UITapGestureRecognizer** like below

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:)))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using base gesture recogniser class, You should use `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- When you are setting constraints programatically on view which is also created programatically the you need to make do following...

  ```
  imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  ```
- The above property need to make `false` to get work constraints programatically.
- Another option is that you just specified the height and width of the constraints but you **didn't specified the *x position* and *y position*.** You need to specify **(X,Y)** position.

**With ImageView**

Using image view you can do the following.

```
func configurePhotoProfile() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
    imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channel?.recipientUrlImage ?? ""))
    imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.selectedSegmentedControl) == 0 {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```

Instead of image you can add `UIButton` to bar button item(with custom view) like below.

```
let vw = UIButton(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34))
vw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

//set buttons other properties

let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: vw)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using base class for gesture recogniser, just use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your code as updated below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            configurePhotoProfile()
        }

        func configurePhotoProfile() {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let widthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
            let heightConstraint = 
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
            heightConstraint.isActive = true
            widthConstraint.isActive = true
            imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channel?.recipientUrlImage ?? ""))
            imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.selectedSegmentedControl) == 0 {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
            }
        }

        @objc func didTapImageButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            print("tap")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a concern with your approach by getting an event using `Gesture`. It would be better to get an event using `IBAction`.

For that, you can add a custom view (`UIView`) in your `NavigationItem` and add `UIImage` and `UIButton` as a subview of that custom view.

Once you are done with the desired `UI` part you can create a `IBAction` for the added button.

Following image is an initial approach of your desired `UI` you can add subviews here

[image]